# Approach to develop a package in R to convert PDF to HTML

Tags: html, r, pdf

I'm working on a project to convert PDF to HTML using R. I know there are no packages in R to do that.

I would highly appreciate if any experts could provide some suggestions or approach. I have an approach to do that with the help of python but I'm looking for some better style.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to stack overflow. I don't think that this question suits here in this community as it is [primarily opinion based](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

- Have a look at an existing (open source) tool that does this. It will enable you to learn. https://github.com/itext/i7j-pdfhtml
- Don't re-invent the wheel. Use language bindings to call an existing library from R.

Have a look at https://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2011/01/01/calling-java-code-from-r/.
Where the author explains how to call Java from R.
If you were to go for this approach, you could use `iText pdfHTML`